# How to save old and new values of columns into Audit table using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using `Spring Boot`, with `Spring Data JPA` and `MS Sql server2014` database for process of saving and updating the entity(javax.persistence) into tables.

As per the requirement we need to audit the every column of all the tables. So i created new table as "Audit" with the respective columns. But I not sure how to save the old and new values and other columns.

Is there any seperate api in spring to support this functinality?

```
create table Audit
(
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  TableName VARCHAR (100)
  ColumnName VARCHAR (100)
  RowId INT,
  OldValue VARCHAR (100),
  NewValue VARCHAR (100),
  Type VARCHAR (100),
  ChangedDate DATETIME,
  ChangedBy VARCHAR (100),
);
```

where "Type" indicates the type of DML operation and "Old value & New value" columns saves pervious and existing values of columns in parent table.

Can I know the best approach to auditing the entity i.e save and update the old and new values along with other relative fields into Audit table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

check out hibernate [envers](https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) its easy to configure (all you have to do is mark your Entity as @Auditable) and it takes care of following:

1. Create audit tables
2. Insert data into the audit table when an entity is inserted/updated/deleted
3. It provides its own query language using which you can get what all has been changed in an entity

**Update**
You can also take a look at [javers](http://javers.org/). I had used javers along with Hibernate's [EntityInterceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events) to capture changes in form of field changed, old value and new value. See javers [Diff](http://javers.org/documentation/diff-examples/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Sarvesh for reply. I implemented auditing using  Hibernate envers and version 4.3.3.  I am able to audit the entity using Audited annoation. But  records not inserted/Audited in to join table using  @AuditJoinTable annotation.

Comment: How are you generating the audit schema? Let hibernate automatically create the audit schema by setting hbm2ddl to auto or create. I am sure you dont need to take care of explicit joins for auditing, hibernate(envers) is smart enough to do that.

Comment: Yes, hiberate everse automatically creating the tables, but records not  inserted in to  audit table of join table.

Comment: Note: I did not mention the  audit schema details in application.properties file in my spring boot.

Comment: @SatishKonda please don't use the comments for new questions. Just create a new question. This will allow others to find the question (and its answers) as well.